# How to change the value of a cell in a row in a CSV file using iterrows()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a script to change the cells of a column named 'ticker', when the cell is a specific name. For example, for all the cells that are 'BRK.B' in the ticker column, I want to change them to 'BRK-B' instead.

Code:

```
company_input = input('What company do you want to change the value of?')
company_input.upper()
print(f'Company chosen is: {company_input}')

company_change = input('What would you like to change the value to?')
company_change.upper()
# For SF1 file
for ticker, row in sf1.iterrows():
    row['ticker'] = company_input
    row['ticker'] = company_change
```

This isn't changing anything in the file and I'm not sure why. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of `iterrows()` it says

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

Instead, to modify all the values in a column, you should use the `apply()` method and define a function to handle changing `BRK.B` to `BRK-B`.

That would look something like this

```py
def change_cell(x): #? x is the original value
    return x.replace(".", "-") #? The return value will be whatever the cell is modified into

df['ticker'] = df['ticker'].apply(change_cell)
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't make any changes to the CSV file. The code executes really quickly and nothing happens.

Comment: Can you share which changes you have made?

Comment: I was making a mistake. It works, sorry about that!